# Why the query is giving result while the destCurrency is not 0 -

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM xyz 
WHERE applyat = 'anita' 
    AND applyAt = 'Create' 
    AND country = '50' 
    AND  dest_country = '108' 
    AND  originCurrency = 'EUR' 
    AND  destCurrency = 0 AND isEnable = 'Y'  
    AND agentID = 0 
    AND Module = 'abc' 
ORDER BY ruleID DESC
```

Comment: What is datatype of `destCurrency` column?

Comment: Is this your actual query, with a table name called xyz? And there are no joins? And destCurrency is not ambiguous?

Comment: [link] varchar(10) @AnkiiGangrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add quotes as it is a varchar

`SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE applyat = 'anita' AND applyAt = 'Create' AND country = '50' AND dest_country = '108' AND originCurrency = 'EUR' AND destCurrency = '0' AND isEnable = 'Y' And agentID = 0 AND Module = 'abc' ORDER BY ruleID DESC`

Comment: still getting the row

Comment: Will that column have `0` or `1` or some other value also?

Comment: i also tried after changing the column type to int and ran the previous query without quotes , even that didn't helped

Comment: Can you paste your database schema with dummy data here?

Comment: sorry schema contains private data :(

Comment: you can add some dummy data and provide to resolve your problem

Comment: changing the datatype helped me . in first attempt there may be some cache problem